# Superset: how to find all charts using a specific table

Tags: apache-superset

I want to delete a table but I am having a hard time figuring out whether the table is used on my Superset instance. Is it possible to list all the charts on Superset with a particular table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to charts and select the dataset. All the charts will be listed.

[image]